# Python TypeError in string formatting code

Tags: python, pseudocode

I have a question where I have to convert from pseudo code into Python and i have an error that goes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Toshiba/Documents/Stevens stuff/Rings work.py", line 16, in <module>
    Rings[i] = int(input(("How many teeth are on ring #i ?") % (i + 1)))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

My code currently looks like:

```
Rings = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
n = 0

while n == 0:
    NumberofRings = int(input("How many rings are on your bike? "))
    if NumberofRings <1 or NumberofRings >8:
        print("Enter a number between 1 and 8")
    else:
        n = n + 1

Rings[0] = int(input("How many teeth are on ring 1? "))

for i in range (1, NumberofRings):
    T = 0
    while T == 0:
        Rings[i] = int(input(("How many teeth are on ring #i ?") % (i + 1)))
        if Rings[1] >= Rings(i - 1):
            print("The number of teeth must be lower that the previious ring")
        else:
            T = 1
print ("=================")

for i in range(0, (len(Rings))):
    print  (("Ring #i has #i teeth") % (i + 1, Rings[i]))
```

Comment: you need a % format mark in your strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression uses `%` to do [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations):

```
("How many teeth are on ring #i ?") % (i + 1)
```

It tells Python to substitute `(i + 1)` in place of a placemarker (e.g. `%s` or `%d`)
in the string `"How many teeth are on ring #i ?"`. But there is no placemarker in the string.
Therefore, Python complains,

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

To fix the error, you probably want

```
("How many teeth are on ring %d ?") % (i + 1)
```

`%s` is used when you want the `str` representation of an object. `%d` is used
when you want to require that the object being formatted is an int.

---

You'll encounter the same error on this line

```
print  (("Ring #i has #i teeth") % (i + 1, Rings[i]))
```

which you can fix similarly.

---

Also,

```
if Rings[1] >= Rings(i - 1):
```

will raise the error

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

because parentheses are used to call functions, while brackets (`[` and `]`) are used to index items in container objects. `Rings(i - 1)` should therefore be `Rings[i-1]`.

If I understand the purpose of the code correctly, it also might be better to use

```
if Rings[i] >= Rings[i - 1]:
```

(note `Rings[i]` instead of `Rings[1]`), since  `Rings[1]` traps the code in an infinite loop if `NumberofRings` is greater than 2.

Comment: Thank you. Very Helpful +1 for you!!